# Error en mostrar mensaje de confirmacion o error

Tags: php, api

Tengo un problema al enviar la confirmacion del envio del formulario, no me esta mostrando ninguno al completar los datos ni al tener problema de envio. El enlace con Mailchimp si funciona perfecto.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$cel = $_POST ['cel'];

if($email) {
    //Create mailchimp API url
    $memberId = md5(strtolower($email));
    $dataCenter = substr($apiKey,strpos($apiKey,'-')+1);
    print $url = 'https://' . $dataCenter . '.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/' . $listId . '/members/' . $memberId;

    //Member info
        $data = array(
            'email_address'=>$email,
            'status' => 'subscribed',
            'merge_fields'  => [
                'FNAME'     => $fname,
                'LNAME'     => $lname,
                'CEL'       => $cel
            ]
            );
    $jsonString = json_encode($data);

    // send a HTTP POST request with curl
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'user:' . $apiKey);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonString);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);

    //Collecting the status
    switch ($httpCode) {
        case 200:
            $msg = '¡Muchisimas gracias! Dentro de poco, nos comunicaremos con vos';
            break;
        case 214:
            $msg = 'Ya estas registrado en nuestra web';
            break;
        default:
            $msg = 'Oops, ocurrio un problema con el mensaje.[msg_code='.$httpCode.']';
            break;
    }
}

header('location:subscribe.php?msg='.$msg);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado! Aca esta el link de la API -> [mailchimp.php](https://github.com/drewm/mailchimp-api)

```
<?php

// Put your MailChimp API and List ID hehe
$api_key = 'MyAPIKEY';
$list_id = 'MyListID';

// Let's start by including the MailChimp API wrapper
include('./inc/MailChimp.php');
// Then call/use the class
use \DrewM\MailChimp\MailChimp;
$MailChimp = new MailChimp($api_key);

// Submit subscriber data to MailChimp
// For parameters doc, refer to: http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/members/
// For wrapper's doc, visit: https://github.com/drewm/mailchimp-api
$result = $MailChimp->post("lists/$list_id/members", [
                        'email_address' => $_POST["email"],
                        'merge_fields'  => ['FNAME'=>$_POST["fname"], 'LNAME'=>$_POST["lname"], 'CEL'=>$_POST["cel"]],
                        'status'        => 'subscribed',
                    ]);

if ($MailChimp->success()) {
    // Success message
    echo "<h3>¡Muchisimas gracias! <br> Dentro de poco, nos pondremos en contacto con vos</h3>";
} else {
    // Display error
    echo $MailChimp->getLastError();
    // Alternatively you can use a generic error message like:
    echo "<h3>Por favor intentenlo de nuevo.</h3>";
}
?>
```